# Spring websocket multiple tomcat servers

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have an app, that uses many tomcats. Also it uses `websockets`. 
Each `tomcat` saves in `userSessionRegistry` some information about connected users.
But if user come to tomcat A, other tomcats B, C, D .. don't know about connected users to tomcat A and their unique queue names. And when i trying do something like this:

```
messageTemplate.converAndSendToUser(userNameConnectedToTomcatA, ...)
```

from tomacats B,C,D it will not send.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similiar problem. I have many balanced server and I need to control a websocket message sending when an event is triggered. The problem is that the user channel can be opened to a different server, how can I "share" the channels between all servers? Did you have the same goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be achieved by implementing UserSessionRegistry. See the DefaultUserDestinationResolver, which is very simple and keeps the data in memory. It can be replaced with something like Redis in order to make it distributed.

This is something that was on my mind to get to. Can you open a request in JIRA so we can track it? Also if you're willing to try to do it I will help you out.

Comment: Is it possible configure DefaultUserDestinationResolver through xml? I use release 4.0.2

Comment: Yes, see this here http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-advanced-xml. Even though it is for the Spring MVC namespace, the idea is exactly the same.